# magento currency code name

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, multicurrency

I have added multiple currencies for single store and all working good except a issue in drop-down. The currency code displaying the same currency code which is default name.

if default code is EUR then EUR will display in all drop-down and if changed the US will display in all drop-down. Though all working good but name displaying same in drop-down.

[image]

[image]

Magento version: 1.9.2.2

Comment: could you show the code?

Comment: Its default currency file dear

Comment: Nope, this can't be default currency switcher. Check the differences between your theme's currency switcher and base theme's currency switcher.

Comment: I used Venus theme and there is no custom code from my end. I need compare the files , i think.